# How to verify Hamilton-Path in log-space?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Given an undirected graph $G$ and an undirected path $p$, Is it possible to verify $p$ is a Hamilton path in graph $G$ using logarithmic space? How is it possible to verify the path goes through all vertices without somehow save which one had been already checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking at every vertex in the path to see if you've visited the whole graph, look at every vertex in the whole graph and see if it's in the path.  If the graph has $n$ vertices and the cycle doesn't, then reject.  Otherwise,

```
for i = 1 to n do
    foundit = false
    for j = 1 to n do
        if path[j] = i then
            foundit = true
    if !foundit then
        return false
return true
```

Storage used is two integer variables, taking $\log n$ bits each, and one Boolean, taking some constant number of bits.

Answer (score 2):

You can check all vertices in order.

Suppose we are given vertices $v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n$ and a path $p=(p_1,p_2, \cdots,p_m)$.Check if $m==n$. If not, reject. Otherwise, check if $v_1$ appears in $p$. If not, reject.  Otherwise, check if $v_2$ appears in $p$. If not reject. And so on. Finally check if $v_m$ appears in $p$. If not, reject. Otherwise, accept.